# Automated Export Failed

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

As admin for an Azure subscription I am getting emails reporting:

> Automated SQL Export failed for {server:database} at 9/5/2013 12:00:11
>   AM. The temporary database copy to export from could not be made.

I deleted this server, without explicitly removing the automated export configuration.

First question: how do I tell Azure to stop trying to do the export?

Second question: newbie mistake (if so please let me know what I failed to do) or bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Just ran into the same thing. Since the export configuration is only present on the settings page for the nonexistent database, this smells like an oversight on Azure's part.

Comment: Looks like this has finally come to the Azure team's attentions:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/a05921e3-801e-4b25-bd67-bb9fea92c8b5/deleting-a-sql-azure-database-does-not-delete-automatic-export-backup-job-resulting-in-daily

Comment: And finally today: "This issue has been corrected"

Comment: We've also had some other issues around Automated Exports where an export cannot be completed/done on a large database (over 130GB or so). Also, many times we would randomly get the message 'Could not load the automated export settings.' on the portal. I believe the Automated Export is still in Preview therefore problems are expected to occur, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this might be because the schema of the database has changed, which has resulted in an object (stored procedure, view, function) becoming invalid.

This problem / solution is elaborated on in another question:

[Automated azure sql export fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857125/automated-azure-sql-export-fails/26661234#26661234)