# Azure SQL tries to create Automated SQL Export after Database being deleted

Tags: sql, azure, export

Because of a [problem exporting v12 Azure SQL databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566610/unable-to-import-sql-azure-v12-bacpac-type-microsoft-data-tools-schema-sql-sql/28573706#28573706) I had to copy my existing database, drop the old one copy the copy again to get the old database name again.

And now the new problem begins: Azure tries to create a backup for the old and non-existing database and sends me hundrets of error emails. As far as I can see there is no way to cancel the errant export through Azure web interface or power shell.

The error message sent by mail is:

> Automated SQL Export failed for : at 13.03.2015
>   14:23:13. The temporary database copy was made, but this copy could
>   not be exported to the .bacpac file.

There was a issue like that before but regarding to [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640131/automated-export-failed) it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be fixed by today. Now it's possible to deactivate the automated database export thru azure management portal again.
You just need to create a database with the same name like the one the automated update was created for.

No official statement from Microsoft found so far.

Answer (score 0):

The issue on Azure Management Portal is fixed last Friday. It should be working as expected.